# Среднее  арифметическое  модулей  разностей всех  элементов  массива

Tags: массивы, java

Доброго времени суток.

Задача стояла такая: вводя 2 целых числа, нужно было найти все простые числа между ними. С этим быстро справился, но вторая часть задания добавляет условие: сгенерировать массив из простых чисел, найденных ранее, при условии, что среднее  арифметическое  модулей  разностей всех  элементов массива наиболее близка к целому числу P > 1 типа int. Число **Р** также вводится вместе с границами диапазона. Разности считаются так: если массив, например, **7 2 2 5**, то среднее арифметическое будет вычисляться так **ср_арф = (|7-2|+|7-2|+|7-5|+|2-2|+|2-5|+|2-5|)/6**.   Сломал весь мозг, но дальше прямого перебора не придумал ничего, вот что я наваял (осторожно говнокод):

```
rezArrList.add(intArrList.get(rand.nextInt(intArrList.size())));
    counter++;
    while (result >= p+1 || result <= p-1 || result != p){
        rezArrList.add(intArrList.get(rand.nextInt(intArrList.size())));
        counter++;
        for (int i = 0; i < rezArrList.size()-1; i++){
            for (int j = 1; j < rezArrList.size(); j++){
                preresult += Math.abs(rezArrList.get(i)-rezArrList.get(j));
            }
        }
        result = preresult/counter;
    }
```

Это срабатывает, но крайне редко, если повезет. Сейчас пытаюсь вывести формулу, но пока что-то не очень выходит.

Comment: Это вам не к нам, а на математику.

Comment: Ок, буду дальше думать, если что придумаю, выложу здесь, может, поможет кому.

Comment: Я правильно понимаю, что вы нашли простые числа 2, 5, 7, и теперь надо сгенерировать подходящий массив, повторив каждое из этих чисел некоторое количество раз?

Answer (score 2):

Отсортируйте массив простых чисел от большего к меньшему.
так например
7 2 2 5 -> 7 5 2 2
Далее отнимайте от семи 5, 2, 2
От 5 отнимайте 2, 2 и т.д.
Количество прохождения цикла сократится вдвое.
Напишите, если нужен код.